# Need help with Spivak calculus exercise $4$ number $12$ of the $3$rd edition.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

Find all numbers $x$ for which

$x + 3^x < 4$

My problem is probably very basic maths, I can deduce that it would be $x<1$ , in fact I predicted it without making any calculations, but I can't show it with maths, could someone lay it out for me and explain how I did that?? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can deduce it. Deducting is something else. Unfortunately they both have "deduction" as a noun form.

Comment: @Joffan , thanks for the feedback, english is not my native language, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Use the facts that (i) $x+3^x$ is increasing on the whole real line; and (ii) what you already noticed that at $x=1$, we have $x+3^x=4$.

Comment: 3 years later I finally understand what you meant. Damn language and math barriers.

Comment: Sometimes it takes awhile. You got there in the end!

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $f(x) = x+3^x$ has $f'(x) = 1 + \ln 3\cdot 3^x > 0$. Thus if $x < 1 \to f(x) < f(1) = 4$. And this is enough to say the solution is $(-\infty, 1)$